# Spring controller and kafka tempalte threading model - can kafkatemplate use multiple threads to send messages?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Here is an example of putting a web request to Kafka using spring controller:

```
@RestController
class KafkaProducerController(val kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, String>) {
    @PutMapping("/track")
    fun sendTopicCallback(@RequestBody body: String): CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> {
        return kafkaTemplate.send("mytopic", body.toString())
            .thenApply { ResponseEntity.ok(it.toString()) }
    }
}
```

The question is - how threads are used in this example?

As I understand spring will pin up one Thread per HTTP request. And each of these threads will put HTTP body to the Kafka template. And after some time (or message amount?) "somebody" (e.g. another thread) will flush messages to the Kafka topic as batch. But what is there are too many requests and threads that put messages? Can I setup multiple threads for batch messages sending?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact the `KafkaProducer` javadocs recommend using a single producer.

However, manual flushing will cause all to block; it is best to let the producer internals manage batching to avoid such problems.